# Uncaught Exception: User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back After Product Import

Tags: magento2.4, magento2.4.5

I was trying to import a list of products via CSV file after which it froze on the "please wait" screen so I had to refresh the page.

I checked the list of products and I can see that the products were successfully created. when I try to edit any of the products, or even create new products, I'm getting this error.

Please HELP!

[image: ERROR SNIP]